# Front-end: Should I sanitize Email Form being sent through Amazon Lambda?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, frontend, amazon-ses, sanitization

I'm a beginner front-end developer. I'm making a simple website for a family member's personal business and part of it has a form for the user to submit their contact info (just a few inputs and a textarea for a message). The submission goes through an amazon lambda function and their Simple Email Service (SES) in order to send the email. Here's Amazon's little tutorial, just for you to get an idea of whats happening in the function.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-send-email-ses/

I have very little idea how malicious code works in most cases. If I don't sanitize the form, will everything be okay or could someone inject some sort of malicious attack somewhere between the execution of the lambda function or the receiver's email? If so, what's the simplest way to sanitize the input to prevent this? All code is done in javascript.

Comment: this isn't really an appropriate SO question, but sanitization never belongs on the front end. it belongs on the backend.  the front end can trivially be bypassed and an attacker can hit your API directly with 0 effort. In this particular case, it doesn't really matter. it's going along to SES which will not let anything malicious through to an email. Sanitization is most needed when saving to a database.

Comment: @bryan60 You say my question isn't focused enough, and then you pretty much answer the specific questions I asked, namely that SES takes care of security stuff and sanitization isn't necessary in this case. I have nothing to edit to reopen this; thanks for the answer...

Comment: It’s not focused enough as it’s asking several questions at once and isn’t dealing with a specific coding problem. Please review the question guidelines for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You should sanitize, but that is not enough. Your frontend will end up calling the lambda. A malicious actor could bypass the browser and call the backend directly. You **should always** sanitize the input in the backend (the lambda in this case) as well.

Comment: sanitization of a form input on the front end is redundant and pointless.